# Равноудаленные блоки DIV

Tags: html, css, php

[пример блоков](http://s6.hostingkartinok.com/uploads/images/2013/11/580b3a4b5a238fca78e04bfa317deaf3.png)

В общем нужно сверстать блоки div так, чтобы они были равноудалены друг от друга, все имеют фиксированную ширину и высоту (как на прикрепленном изображении). Проблема в том, что информация в эти блоки выводится из БД с помощью php и соответственно нужно для всех 3-х блоков применить один класс CSS (засунуть один блок в цикл и дальше уже в зависимости от того, сколько в БД материалов, выводить нужное кол-во блоков). Если в классе CSS прописать отступ справа к примеру 20px, то 3-ий блок будет съезжать вниз из за нехватки места по ширине страницы.

Если бы страница была статична, то можно бы было у Левого блока сделать обтекание слева а у Правого справа, а у центрального блока сделать равный отступ с обеих сторон в зависимости от ширины страницы. Но тут надо прописывать 3 класса для 3 блоков соответственно, мне же нужно уместить всё в одном классе.

Надеюсь подробно описал суть проблемы.

Comment: ну и ставьте всем блокам "float:left;display:inline-block", они и будут располагаться в строчку по очереди.

Comment: ну так расстояние то между этими блоками будет не одинаковое, точнее отступов вообще не будет

Comment: @xenon, если размеры блоков действительно фиксированные и надо при разном их количестве разместить от края до края родительского блока, при этом задав равные отступы, то одними средствами css, а уж тем более одним классом - это сделать не удастся. А если учесть, что размеры просматриваемой области у разных пользователей будут значительно разниться, то при таких условиях, в пору использовать js. Высчитывать общую доступную ширину, вычесть суммарную ширину блоков, которые будут в одной строке и оставшуюся ширину разкидать на margin между ними.

Comment: Есть пару способов, как этого можно решить поставленную задачу. Надо только уточнить след. моменты:

 1. Ширина блока-обертки этих div'ов фиксированная или резиновая?
 2. Блоки будут выводится по три штуки в ряд? Или в последнем ряду может быть и два блока, и один? И если будет два блока, то как они дожны располагаться (на позиции 1-го и 2-го или 1-го и 3-го блоков)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну можно сделать что-то вроде этого.
Задать стили:

```
.block {margin-right: 20px;}
.last {margin-right: 0px;}
```

Далее, по циклу:

```
$count = 1;

while () { // это ваш цикл

    echo '<div class="block '.$newclass.'">Текст, который выводится из запроса к БД</div>';
    //в конце цикла каждому третьему блоку задаем дополнительный класс last
    if ($count == 3) {$newclass = 'last'; $count = 1;} else {$newclass = ''; $count++;}

}
```

Comment: и кому, интересно, придумали псевдоклассы - :last-child

.block div{margin-right: 20px;display:inline-block;}
.block div:last-child {margin-right: 0px;}
<div class="block">
<div>1</div><div>2</div><div>3</div><div>4</div><div>5</div>
</div>

и без всяких IF'ов.

Comment: нужно каждому третьему выставить margin-right: 0px;, а это совсем не  :last-child

Comment: тогда `className:nth-of-type(3n) { margin-right: 0px; }`

Answer (score 1):

Иногда я заключаю эти ваши множество блоков в обертку и указываю ей `text-align: center`. А самим блокам внутри, соответственно, `display: inline-block`.

Answer (score 0):

Пример 1 - Использование `text-align: justify`

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
div {
  text-align: justify;
  font-size: 0;
}
div:after {
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  overflow: hidden;
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
}
div > div {
  background: #ссс;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  line-height: normal;
  font-size: 14px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
</div>
```

Пример 2 - Использование `display: flex` и `justify-content: space-between`

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.wrap {
  display: -webkit-box;                       /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
  display: -moz-box;                          /* OLD - Firefox 19- (buggy but mostly works) */
  display: -ms-flexbox;                       /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
  display: -webkit-flex;                      /* NEW - Chrome */
  display: flex;                              /* NEW, Spec - Opera 12.1, Firefox 20+ */
  -webkit-justify-content:space-between;      /*Chrome */
  justify-content: space-between;             /* NEW, Spec - Opera 12.1, Firefox 20+ */  
}
.wrap > div {
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: #fff;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div>box 1</div>
  <div>box 2</div>
  <div>box 3</div>  
</div>
```